# How to retrieve an object with a parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to select a certain user based on a user_id but am having some trouble.  I'm getting an error saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10":

The relevant parts of the code are below:

## urls.py

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'view_reviews_user'),
```

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    quote = models.CharField('About', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def view_reviews_user(request, user_id):
    reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    reviews = reviews.order_by("-created_on")
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_id)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/user.html', {'reviews':reviews, 'user_id': user_id, 'userprofile': userprofile},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I believe the error is in the "pk=user_id" but am not sure how to fix it.  I tried "user_id=user_id" but that does't seem to work either.  I am trying to access "quote" in the template eventually.  Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that user_id is an integer value?

Comment: Is that really all the code you have in your view, or did you cut parts out? The error you got indicates the value of `user_id` is something that is not an integer or can't be transformed into an integer (a string with a number, i.e. `'3'`). Please paste *all* the code for your view, and perhaps the relevant lines from your urlconf as well.

Comment: ... and the exact traceback, showing the line that's causing the error.

Comment: @ChrisPratt you're right, I cut parts out and the user_id argument is not just an integer.

Comment: Give us also: 1) definition of the remaining visible models, 2) list of your `urls`, 3) information on the line where the error appeared, 4) preferably full traceback.

Comment: @sharataka: I have pasted the traceback into your question.

Comment: The `user_id` should be an int, like `submeup.com/user/5` instead of `submeup.com/user/sharat`.

And please DO NOT have `DEBUG = True` in deployment. I just went to your link and I can see the `DEBUG` is on. This is like asking hackers to hack you. TURN IT OFF!!!!!!

Comment: Refer to my answer on how to make sure user does not type `sharat` for username, but only a valid integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember what is going on before the view gets called.

Django does regex to match the url with some pattern. Now usually regex expressions will have groups in them to be able to parse out some ids from there. Django will take those ids and pass them to the view. However since it just uses regex, the values of those groups will be strings even if your groups are something like `(?P<user_id>\d+)`.

So within your view, `user_id` is a string, whereas foreign key in your model is an integer, hence Django wants an integer to do the query. All you have to do is cast the value to an integer and you should be fine (refer below on how to make sure the `user_id` does not contain other non-integer characters in it):

```
def view_reviews_user(request, user_id):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=int(user_id))
```

---

Even though that will work, many things can go wrong here.

**What about if the user does not type an integer?** That is easily fixed in the regex in urlconfig by using `\d+` which will only match the expression if there are only integers. So then you can be sure that `int(user_id)` will not raise an issue.

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'view_reviews_user'),
```

**What about if the user is not found?** user might provide `user_id` but that user id might not exist. You should handle that. The easiest way is to use django shortcut `get_object_or_404` like:

```
get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=user_id)
```

---

PS: It's not recommended to use a foreign key to a `User` within `UserProfile`. Since there is one-to-one relationship between users and their profiles, you should user `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to query users by their username instead of their id, you can do that like:

```
def view_reviews_user(request, username):
    userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user__username=username)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_id` is a string. Django ids are ints, if you want to use a string like `'sharat'` you should add a `SlugField` to your model, and then query the slug:

```
def view_reviews_user(request, slug):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=slug)
```